# Questions that have been closed should not be returned in "Unanswered Questions"

Tags: feature-request

If a question has been closed because it's doesn't fit the requirements of the community, then shouldn't it be excluded from the http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions as well as the tag statistics?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think so. Questions that are on hold or closed are still visible to everyone, and could be improved and re-opened. After a certain amount of time, closed questions without enough positive activity are automatically deleted by the system and won't be shown.

If you specifically want to filter out on hold/closed questions, you can add the appropriate constraint to your query.

Comment: Valid point..  I just thought since a question is closed and can't be answered until it's edited (most of the time by the user) it shouldn't be included. For instance, if a question has been marked off-topic and thus closed, the question can't really be made to be on topic in most cases can it? Therefore wouldn't it make more sense for those to be removed from the /unanswered call and tag stats.

Comment: Actually, it can be made on-topic. Quite often, depending on the sub-reason.